# Not able to update firefox sqlite database when firefox is running-MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite

I have the following code snippet to update firefox extension sqlite data base

```
NSString * profileFolderPath = [[ @"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles"];
    NSString *sqlitePath = [pathToProfileFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"extensions.sqlite"];

    int rc = sqlite3_open([sqlitePath UTF8String], &db);
    if( rc )
    {
        NSLog(@"enable extension :%@\n",[NSString stringWithCString:sqlite3_errmsg(db)]);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"opened entensions db successfully \n");
    }
    // check the values for active and userDisabled fields
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db,"SELECT active,userDisabled FROM addon where id='myId.com'",sqliteCallback,0,&zErrMsg);
    if (rc!=SQLITE_OK ) {
        NSLog(@"error quering the entensions database  :%@\n",[NSString stringWithCString:zErrMsg]);
        if(zErrMsg)
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return NO;
        //  handle error
    }
```

When firefox application is not in running state,I can read the values and also update the database,but when the firefox is running I am not able to read the values from the database as  sqlite3_exec statement is returning the value 5 and I can see the error in console saying "error quering the extensions database  :database is locked".

How can I resolve this issue.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot b/c firefox keeps its own config file (and extensions db file IS a firefox own config file) open while it runs.